# GCC - Linux - Set the stack to zero before returning?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly

#### Context

Linux 64 bits

#### Question

Is it possible to instruct the stack to be zeroed before returning a function ?

I want not valid information left on the stack, even if overwritten right after by other values.
I explicitly want to waste some time doing so.

Is it possible in an automated manner **that cannot be bypassed** when compiled in a controlled environment ?

Thanks

Comment: May I ask why do you wanna do such thing?

Comment: Automating that will almost certainly not be possible unless you are willing to patch your compiler. C++ would let you use destructors for non-POD types, but no such thing in C (and no way of doing it on POD types in C++ anyway). However, you can always add a scope and overwrite storage, like so: `void foo() { {/* actual function goes here*/} volatile int x[1000]={}; }`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by “cannot be bypassed when compiled in a controlled environment”.

Comment: There may be an easier way to do it (I don't know of any). But one way would be to use the "-finstrument-functions" option. This allows you to hook in an entry and exit function for each regular function call entry and exit. You could clear the stack in the exit hook. As the name suggests its primarily used for instrumentation. But nothing to stop you from using it for other purposes.

Comment: Lol, set stack to nulls and return.....where?

Comment: @MartinJames he obviously meant the current stack frame, not the whole stack.

Comment: @Alan: Thanks, those hooks seem perfect, +1 Alan. Would you mind making it an answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use the "-finstrument-functions" option. This allows you to hook in an entry and exit function for each regular function call entry and exit. You could clear the stack in the exit hook. As the name suggests its primarily intended for instrumentation. But nothing to stop you from using it for other purposes.